# Sub-tables no Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, front-end

Estou criando uma table convencional, que quando clicada no no nome do grupo ela mostra uma sub-tabela contendo as mesmas colunas e refatorando os resultados:

ESTADO NORMAL:

```
 GRUPOS    QUANTIDADE
|  GA   |  |  1000  |
|  GB   |  |  1600  |
```

QUANDO CLICADA NO TITULO DO GRUPO:

```
 GRUPOS    QUANTIDADE
|  GA   |  |  1000  |
| CLI01 |  |  500   |
| CLI02 |  |  500   |

|  GB   |  |  1600  |
| CLI01 |  |  800   |
| CLI02 |  |  800   |
```

A PARTIR DE UMA ESTRUTURA DA TABLE ABAIXO, O QUE É NECESSÁRIO APLICAR PARA QUE APAREÇA AS SUB TABELAS E QUE ELAS TENHAM ESTE EFEITO DE 'SHOW/HIDE'?

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>GRUPOS</th>
        <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>GA</td>
        <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GB</td>
        <td>1600</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nao sei se você quer tipo uma `treetable`, mas vai seguir o mesmo contexto.

```js
$('ul li span').on('click', function(){
        $('.show').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.show{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li>
            <span>A</span>
            <div class="show">VVVV</div>
              
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Segue esse exemplo, caso nao funcione, ou nao seja isso que queira, poste seu codigo atual, que partimos dele.

Comment: É exatamente o que eu preciso. Eu só não estou conseguindo colocar os trechos que você comentou em uma página que funcione. O que entra dentro de <script> </script>? Onde eu coloco o ".show{ display: none; }"

Comment: Consegui :) muito obrigado.